# Changing where a C++ Pointer is pointing to

Tags: java, c++

I am getting confused comparing `Java` and `C++` references:

In the below code in java the `Point p` object is still pointing to the `(5,5)` object after calling `changePoint`.

This is because the `temp` variable (in `chagePoint`) is allocated on the stack and holds a reference to the `p` object (in `main`) in the heap but when we reassign temp it just points to another point object in the heap without changing where the original `Point p` object in main is pointing to.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    Point p = new Point(5,5);
    changePoint(p);
}

changePoint(Point temp) {
    temp = new Point(4,6);
}
```

Now in C++ if we do the same thing what happens to the `(5,5)` object in main after exeucting those two statements in `changePoint`? When you do `*temp = new Point(4,5)` it will simply override the `(5,5)` object that `p` is pointing to from main correct? But when you do temp = new Point(4,5) will the `(5,5)` object in main will be a memory leak?

```
int main() {
    Point *p = new Point(5,5);
    changePoint(&p);
}

changePoint(Point *temp) {
    *temp = new Point(4,5);
    temp = new Point (5,6);
}
```

Comment: **−1** Your code will not compile. Please only post **real code**. It's meaningless to discuss what code that wouldn't compile, would do if it compiled.

Comment: To remove confusion, don't compare them.  They are different languages.  The C++ language has pointers *and* references, and they are different.

Comment: Your C++ code isn't using references, it is using pointers.  The pointers are passed to the function by copy.  Your function is not modifying the content of the original pointer variable.

Comment: @1290 `*temp = new Point(4,5);` overrides contents of instance where `temp` is pointing to. `temp = new Point (5,6);` overrides `temp` but it is provided by value. Change signature of `changePoint` to `changePoint(Point *&temp)` to make `temp` a reference parameter. Check this out in your debugger...

Comment: @Scheff: Before he can check things out in a debugger he would have to correct the code so that it compiles. Then with the changed code it may be that your comment doesn't make sense any more.

Comment: _@1290_ `changePoint(Point *temp)` doesn't use the pointer by reference, but by value. Instead of passing the address of the pointer, make it a reference here: `changePoint(Point *& temp)`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews OP may have worded it badly, but they are comparing Java references to C++ pointers.  Java references are more similar to C++ pointers than to C++ references

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Ah, I see. `*temp = new Point(4,5);` might probably produce a compile error (except `Point`does provide a rather strange conversion constructor or assignment operator.)

Comment: @Scheff: Well I reacted first to `&p` as actual argument (a `Point**` as actual argument), but also `changePoint` lacks a return type, and at least one of the two assignments, to `*temp` and `temp`, must necessarily fail to compile. It's just fantasy rubbish code. Nobody can predict what it would be if corrected.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf In ancient times, no type meant `int` but I'm not sure if it is even allowed in C++11. Of courrse, I never used this option in daily business for years...

Comment: No, implicit int has never been part of standard C++. It was there in K&R C, and I believe it's still part of C.

Comment: Your Java explanation seems overly complicated. `p` is passed to `changePoint` by value - it receives a copy of the reference. Then it assigns to that copy, so the original reference is unchanged. Nothing in there relates to the actual `Point` object referred to by either reference. And this is exactly how pointers work in C++.

Comment: I wish I could upvote the "Java is not C++" comment again.  The two languages are different, period, full-stop.

Comment: @chris Thank you for the clarification. That simplified a lot of my doubts combined with Thomas post below. Sorry for the confusion on the post I was in a hurry while writing. Will keep this in mind next time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should understand the following before comparing to Java:

1. C++ pass by reference vs. pass by value (copy).
2. Pointers to pointers.

In C++ if you want to modify the variable that was passed to a function, you need to pass by reference:

```
void func1(int& value)
{
  value = 5;
}
void another_function()
{
  int number = 0;
  func(number);
  std::cout << "The value of number is: " << number << "\n";
}
```

The value of `number` will be changed by `func` because the variable is passed by reference.

If you want to modify variable using pointers instead of references, you will need to pass a pointer:

```
void func2(int * pointer_to_value)
{
  *pointer_to_value = 16;
}
void caller()
{
  int number = 0;
  func2(&number);
  std::cout << "The value of number is: " << number << "\n";
}
```

If you want to change a pointer, without passing by reference, you need to pass a pointer to the pointer:

```
void func3(int * * pointer_to_point_to_value)
{
  *pointer_to_pointer_to_value = new int;
  **pointer_to_pointer_to_value = 23;
}
void caller3()
{
  int * pointer_to_number;
  func3(&pointer_to_number);
  cout << "Number is: " **pointer_to_number << "\n";
}
```

A simpler method is to pass a pointer by reference:

```
void func4(int * & pointer_to_value)
{
  pointer_to_value = new int;
  *pointer_to_value = 17;
}
void caller4()
{
  int * pointer_to_number;
  func4(pointer_to_number);
}
```

As far as arrays go, simplify your life and use `std::vector`.  Pass the vector variable by reference or if you won't modify it, by constant reference.